# How do I represent a buy out of my team on my resume?

Tags: resume, company, name

My business unit (X) was part of a large well-known company (Y). Last year it was purchased by a small company (Z) (not very known) and became a subsidiary of (Z) and became X LLC. I moved with the team from the large company (Y) and still hold the same position.

On my resume, do I separate out my time from when I was with Company Y? Or do I list both companies and then the role?

Can I put something like this:
X LLC (Previously Y)  08/2016- Present
Y                     01/2016-08/2016
Title
Achievements
>
>
>

Separating out the two seems like it would take up too much room.

Comment: If the role is the same then I would combine

Answer (score 1):

I would list it something like this:

> Company B (previously known as Company A)
>
> Position A (8/2016 - Present)
>
> - Achievements
>
> Position B (1/2016-8/2016)
>
> - Achievements

Comment: Unless your actual role changed through the buy out I would not list as two separate positions.

Answer (score -1):

### **It depends**.

Here are two ways to proceed out of many possibilities out there:

1. The moment you changed companies (or the parties that were responsible for your payment changed), your experience with the first ended and that with your second began.

   PROS: 
   This automatically gives you experience with two companies, and that's good. 
   Also, if your previous employer was large, you can state that on your  resume, thereby adding more value than the lesser-known company that made the acquisition.

   CONS:
   If this happened in a short term, you may be perceived as a job hopper.

   **SOLUTION**:
   In your description of second company, mention that it acquired your team from the previous one, and then, if possible, list out your achievements/projects post the acquisition.
2. State complete experience as being under the new company. Considering that your team hasn't changed, your experience would have been one continuous stretch from when you began working in the team.

   PROS: Continuous experience can be perceived as loyalty. Also, you get to talk about your whole duration of your stay with the team in one shot during your interview, highlighting some of your greatest accomplishments on the team.

   CONS: You may be perceived as hiding something, and may goof up if asked about people at company Z before the acquisition.

   **SOLUTION**:
   Highlight that you were on team X, formerly with company Y, until the acquisition  of your awesome team by company Z. You're still in team X, but with Z.

For instance, people who worked in YouTube may now claim to be working with Google, or Alphabet Inc. even though nothing much may have changed about the work they do.

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer, and this is not legal advice. Your resume is merely a ticket to an interview, which is the real place that you've to impress people. The decision rests with you. So, good luck!

Comment: Why the downvote? Suggestions for improvements are welcome :)

Comment: Could be because you're abusing the formatting. You may want to move your answer to the linked parent question, this has been closed as duplicate.

Comment: Thank you @Lilienthal : But what happens to the reputation if I remove it from here? Also, the pointed question is about entire companies being acquired whereas this one is only about a team. So that's different , IMO> Whatsay?

Comment: Could you help with formatting please?

Comment: Your answer here is on +0/-2. If you delete it here the rep loss will disappear and you can repost (a reworked version of) your answer on the linked question to start from a clean slate. And the question is about listing a position after a change in ownership, scope of the acquisition doesn't seem important but if you think it's substantially different you can edit this to nominate for reopen, ask input in [chat] (+20 rep) or create a thread about it on [meta]. For formatting: removing the excessive bold is good, I'd also suggest removing the quote syntax since you're not quoting anything.

Comment: Thanks you for the feedback on the formatting.I hope it is better now. I feel the scope of acquisition is very relevant because the OP and the team have continued working on their thing. Furthermore, it has spun off into an LLC of their own. So while on the surface, it seems like OP's employer has merely moved from company Y to Company X, acquired by Z, this is not of their own free will. There hasn't been movement by OP(resignation, termination),  so that's another reason why this isn't a duplicate. Your thoughts?